Using the Martingale Representation Theorem to generalize the Geometric Brownian Motion
I'm having trouble understanding the reasoning given in a proof of the following theorem in the book A First Course in Statistic Calculus by Louis-Pierre Arguin.

Theorem 7.26. Let $(M_t, t \in [0, T])$ be a continuous martingale with respect to the filtration $(\mathcal{F_t}, t \leq T)$ with $M_0 = 0$ and with quadratic variation $\left\langle M \right\rangle_t = t$. Then $(M_t, t \leq T)$ is a standard Brownian motion.

The exposition is as follows:

The Martingale Representation Theorem implies that we can write $M_t = \int_{0}^{t} V_s \mathrm{d}B_s$ for some adapted process $(V_t, t \leq T)$. For simplicity, we assume that $V_s$ is such that the process (7.17) is a martingale.
7.17. (A generalization of geometric Brownian motion). Consider $(\int_{0}^{t}V_s \mathrm{d}B_s, t \geq 0)$ an Itô process. Define the positive process $M_t = \exp\bigg(\int_{0}^{t} V_s \mathrm{d}B_s - \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t} V^2_s\mathrm{d}s\bigg), t \geq 0$
We show that the increments of $M$ are independent with the right distribution. In fact, we show that for $0 \leq s \lt t \leq T$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, we have:
${\bf E}[\exp(\lambda(M_t − M_s))|\mathcal{F}_s] = e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2}(t-s)}$
Consider for $t \geq s$ the process:
$Y_t = \exp\bigg(\lambda(M_t - M_s) - \frac{\lambda^2}{2}\int_{s}^{t} V^2_u \mathrm{d}u\bigg) = \exp\bigg(\lambda\int_{s}^{t} V_u \mathrm{d}B_u - \frac{\lambda^2}{2}(t-s)\bigg)\tag{1}$
Note that $Y_s = 1$. As discussed in Example 7.17, this is a martingale. This implies:
$1 = {\bf E}\big[Y_t|\mathcal{F}_s] = {\bf E}[\exp(\lambda(M_t − M_s) −\frac{\lambda^2}{2}(t-s))|\mathcal{F}_s\big] \tag{2}$

In (1), how do we get to the last equality? Is it true that $\int_{s}^{t} V^2_u \mathrm{d}u = (t-s)$?
If so, can someone explain why and confirm whether (2) follows by taking the first term from the middle expression in (1) (implying $M_t - M_s = \int_{s}^{t} V_u \mathrm{d}B_u$) with the second term in final expression in (1)? Otherwise, can someone please fill me in on how we get the last expression in (1) and and then how we get (2)?

To answer your first question: $$ \int_{s}^{t} V^2_u \mathrm{d}u = \Big{(}\int_{0}^{t} V^2_u \mathrm{d}u - \int_{0}^{s} V^2_u \mathrm{d}u \Big{)} =  \Big{(} \langle M \rangle _t - \langle M \rangle _s \Big{)} = (t-s)$$
The first equality follows by splitting up the integral. The second and third equalities follow from the assumptions on $M$.

To answer your second question, I have made it is easier to follow by rearranging the equalities and adding in one extra step in red:
$$ {\bf E}[\exp(\lambda(M_t − M_s) −\frac{\lambda^2}{2}(t-s)|\mathcal{F}_s\big] = {\bf E}\big[Y_t|\mathcal{F}_s] \color{red}{ = Y_s} = 1 $$
The first equality comes by substituting the result for $Y_t$ explained above. The second equality comes from the fact that $Y$ is a martingale (which your question notes is already "discussed in Example 7.17). The final equality simply comes from the fact that if we substitute $t = s$ into the definition of $Y$, we get $e^0$ which is $1$.
